# How to fix this up? " Unknown action The action 'index' could not be found for UsersController"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When I go to my localhost:3000/users page, I get:
Unknown action
The action 'index' could not be found for UsersController.

Answer (score 8):

If you were following [Hartl's tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#code:first_create_action),then accessing localhost:3000/users will cause this error. Try localhost:3000/signup instead.

Answer (score 3):

You need not define the default actions (assuming appropriate http method), all you need to do is add the following to your config/routes.rb

```
resources :users
```

Answer (score 3):

First you need to make sure that your controller actually has an index action, so

`class UsersController < ApplicationController` has to include the `def index ... end` in it.
Also, make sure your routes are set up correctly using

```
resources :users
```

and check it by typing

```
rake routes
```

in the terminal to check that the routes are right.
You might also want to check that the `root` is set up correctly in the config/routes.rb file

Answer (score 2):

if you got the same problem with me (I cant access the localhost:3000/users but I can access my localhost:3000/signup), it might be works for u.
First, in your users_controller.rb (Controller for Users) , add

```
def index 
end
```

Then , make a file "index/html/erb" in your app/views/users/index.html.erb
and put this code

```
<% controller.redirect_to "/signup" %>
```

You might have to rerun your server, and it works on my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, if you've included

```
get 'signup'  => 'users#new 
resources :users
```

…in your `routes.rb` file, then you need to use localhost:3000/signup instead.  I believe if you removed `get 'signup'  => 'users#new` and left only `resources :users` then using localhost:3000/users would take you to the new user signup form.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `debugger` line. Also, make sure you have `exit` the rails console.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    debugger
  end

  def new
  end
end
```